# One to many join with sums in both tables; how to handle duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

I have the following scenario -

Item sales:

```
    ╔═════╦════════╦════════════╗
    ║ SKU ║ ItemId ║ SaleAmount ║
    ╠═════╬════════╬════════════╣
    ║ 123 ║      1 ║ $45.99     ║
    ║ 456 ║      2 ║ $54.99     ║
    ╚═════╩════════╩════════════╝
```

Sale coupons:

```
    ╔═════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
    ║ SKU ║ CouponId ║ CouponAmount ║
    ╠═════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
    ║ 123 ║        1 ║ $4           ║
    ║ 123 ║        2 ║ $5           ║
    ║ 123 ║        3 ║ $2           ║
    ║ 456 ║        1 ║ $2           ║
    ╚═════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Desired end result

```
    ╔═════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
    ║ SKU ║ SaleAmount ║ CouponAmount ║
    ╠═════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
    ║ 123 ║ $45.99     ║ $11          ║
    ║ 456 ║ $54.99     ║ $2           ║
    ╚═════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I already have this working by joining a filtered `item sales` query to a filtered `sale coupons` query and grouping by `sku`, however I want to know if there is a better way to do this that doesn't result in the `SaleAmount` being duplicated for each record in `sale coupons`.  i.e. if you were to just do a `LEFT JOIN` on `sale coupons` and `SUM(SaleAmount), SUM(CouponAmount)` and `GROUP BY SKU`, you'd get -

```
    ╔═════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
    ║ SKU ║ SaleAmount ║ CouponAmount ║
    ╠═════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
    ║ 123 ║ $137.97    ║ $11          ║
    ║ 456 ║ $54.99     ║ $2           ║
    ╚═════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Which is correct for `sku=456`, but falls apart when there is more than one corresponding `sale coupon` record.

Comment: which database you uses? Orable, Mysql etc? please add it into the tag.

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Pre summarise `Coupons` so it's a one to one, then join. You pre summarise by using a subtable.

Comment: Expanding on the above comment, one way you can do it is by using a subquery that selects the SKU and SUM of the coupon amount from the coupons table (grouping by SKU) and then join that to your item table.

Comment: Kindly find the answer i posted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH S AS 
(
   SELECT SKU, SUM(SaleAmount) AS SaleAmount
   FROM Sales
   GROUP BY SKU
), 
C AS 
(
   SELECT SKU, SUM(CouponAmount) AS CouponAmount
   FROM Coupons
   GROUP BY SKU
)
SELECT ISNULL(S.SKU, C.SKU) AS SKU, S.SaleAmount, C.CouponAmount
FROM S FULL OUTER JOIN C ON S.SKU = C.SKU
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
;with item_sales as (
select 
123 as sku
,1 as itemid
,45.99 as salesamount

union all

select 
456 as sku
,2 as itemid
, 54.99 as salesamount
)
Select item_sales.* into #itemsales from item_sales


;with mycte as (
select 
123 as sku
,1 as couponid
,4 as couponamount

union all

select 
123 as sku
,2 as couponid
,5 as couponamount
union all

select 
123 as sku
,3 as couponid
,2 as couponamount
union all

select 
456 as sku
,1 as couponid
,2 as couponamount
)

Select
 mycte.sku
 ,ist.salesamount
 ,sum(couponamount )  as couponamount 
from mycte

inner join #itemsales  ist
    on  ist.sku = mycte.sku
group by 
 mycte.sku
 ,ist.salesamount

 drop table #itemsales
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. You need to group by with SKU and SaleAmount

> ```
>     select i.sku,SaleAmount,sum(CouponAmount) as CouponAmount from item i join sale s 
>     on i.sku=s.sku group by i.sku,i.SaleAmount
> --Edited
> ```

Comment: Without pre-summarising the item table, that will do exactly the same thing - double count!

Comment: Sorry I did try but it wouldn't let me unless you edit it.

Comment: I undid my downvote - sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't feel it is any better than any other answer though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166508/discussion-between-yahya-mukhtar-and-nick-mcdermaid).